Search function unable to find numbers
I'm using Google Apps Script and JavaScript to search through the data on a spreadsheet.
Rows 0 and 2 - 5 all have a combination of numbers and letters and return results without issue. Row 1 has only numbers, and returns no search results at all from any rows when uncommented.
I also tried to change this to number, row 1 still returns no results
<div>
  <label for="search-box" class="form-label">Search</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search-box" placeholder="Input Status or Recent
    User here." onchange="search()">
</div>
<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Asset Number</th>
        <th scope="col">Recent User</th>
        <th scope="col">Last Sync</th>
        <th scope="col">Status</th>
        <th scope="col">OS Version</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table-body">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
  function search() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(data) {
      let searchText = document.getElementById("search-box")
      let tableBody = document.getElementById("table-body")
      tableBody.innerHTML = ""
      let filterData = data.filter(row => row[0].toUpperCase().match(searchText.value.toUpperCase()) ||
        row[1].toUpperCase().match(searchText.value.toUpperCase()) ||
        row[2].toUpperCase().match(searchText.value.toUpperCase()) ||
        row[3].toUpperCase().match(searchText.value.toUpperCase()) ||
        row[4].toUpperCase().match(searchText.value.toUpperCase()) ||
        row[5].toUpperCase().match(searchText.value.toUpperCase()))
      filterData.forEach(row => {
        let tableRow = document.createElement("tr")
        let ouData = document.createElement("td")
        ouData.textContent = row[0]
        tableRow.appendChild(ouData)
        let aNumberData = document.createElement("td")
        aNumberData.textContent = row[1]
        tableRow.appendChild(aNumberData)
        let rUserData = document.createElement("td")
        rUserData.textContent = row[2]
        tableRow.appendChild(rUserData)
        let lSyncData = document.createElement("td")
        lSyncData.textContent = row[3]
        tableRow.appendChild(lSyncData)
        let rActivityData = document.createElement("td")
        rActivityData.textContent = row[4]
        tableRow.appendChild(rActivityData)
        let sData = document.createElement("td")
        sData.textContent = row[5]
        tableRow.appendChild(sData)
        tableBody.appendChild(tableRow)
      })
    }).returnTable()

  }

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(data) {
    let tableBody = document.getElementById("table-body")
    data.forEach(row => {
      let tableRow = document.createElement("tr")
      let ouData = document.createElement("td")
      ouData.textContent = row[0]
      tableRow.appendChild(ouData)
      let aNumberData = document.createElement("td")
      aNumberData.textContent = row[1]
      tableRow.appendChild(aNumberData)
      let rUserData = document.createElement("td")
      rUserData.textContent = row[2]
      tableRow.appendChild(rUserData)
      let lSyncData = document.createElement("td")
      lSyncData.textContent = row[3]
      tableRow.appendChild(lSyncData)
      let rActivityData = document.createElement("td")
      rActivityData.textContent = row[4]
      tableRow.appendChild(rActivityData)
      let sData = document.createElement("td")
      sData.textContent = row[5]
      tableRow.appendChild(sData)
      tableBody.appendChild(tableRow)
    })

  }).returnTable()
</script>


Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please describe the relevant parts of your spreadsheet, including sample data as text, add the server-side code (.gs file), and the expected result corresponding to the sample data.
